# google apps script find()

Tags: google-apps-script, directory

I am looking for more documentation on the find() method in the folder class.  I am getting mixed results with ...find(".pdf") and am looking for a reliable way to find pdf files in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting too many results that aren't necessarily pdfs, maybe try further filtering the result set by checking that the file name extension ends in .pdf.

```
var files = myFolder.find(".pdf");
var pdfs = [];
for (var i in files) {
  var name = files[i].getName();
  var ext = name.substr(-4); // gets last 4 chars of the name
  if (ext == ".pdf") {
    pdfs.push(files[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The strange thing was I was not getting all the pdf files.  I could not find any documentation on how the find() method worked so was not sure what was going on.  I will probably just code around it looking at the extension like you suggest.  Thanks